# Differentiate Context, Request Context in django

Tags: django, django-templates

What is the difference between Context, Request Context in django?
Why do we need context processors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RequestContext` simply goes through your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting and adds variables in addition to the ones you explicitly pass to the context class.

The context processors are literally just a function that accepts `request` as the first argument and returns a dictionary to be added into the context.

Why do you need them? Because some very common operations like adding the currently logged in user or `STATIC_URL` variables to the context would get highly repetitive if not automated.